# Movie Detail View Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, routes, view, ng-view

i´m new in AngularJS and i'm trying to do a Detail view from a list of movies , when you select one movie (clicking in the title) from the 'home' view its supposed to redirect you to the new view with the details of that selected movie ,but i can't figure out how to do it. i saw a lot of tutorials but any works for me , hope you can help me,thanks !!

here is part of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/3fu0gr81/

this is a example of my json file:

```
[{ "Title": "Birdman",

    "Plot": "A washed-up actor, who once played an iconic superhero, battles his ego and attempts to recover his family, his career and himself in the days leading up to the opening of his Broadway play.",

    "Year": "2014",

    "Director": "Alejandro González Iñárritu",

    "Genre": "Comedy",

    "Duration": "119 min",
```

}]

Comment: why not invoke the factory in movieDetail controller only and not in controller1

Comment: thank you , im going to fix that , but I don't have my question solved yet

Comment: you can create a service and pass the data between controllers using that service

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.controller('MovieDetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$http',function($scope,$routeParams,$http){
    $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'movie.json'

    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.movies = data;
    });

}]);
```

here the $scope.movies containing all movies data

by using ng-repeat u can print this in view

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
   <li>{{movie.name}}</li>
</div>
```

If u want particular movie means ,u have to filter with $routeParams.movieId

$scope.filterId = $routeParams.movieId;

and also u can get single record through service also

```
myApp.controller('MovieDetail', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$http',function($scope,$routeParams,$http){
    $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'movie.json',
            params:{"id":"$routeParams.MovieId"}
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.movies = data;
    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code storing the movie data in the service and accessing it in the controller after the view is changed. You may notice I'm not using the `$scope` variable anywhere and that's personal preference.  I feel that using `controller as` syntax is more semantic and easier to understand.  If you have questions let me know.

The application follows this path now:

1) invoke the list method of the `movie service` to load the movie data using `$http` service

2) Store that data in a private object accessible by a method on the `Movie service` and pass it back to the controller

3) Create a link in the view for each movie title containing the title of the movie as a route parameter

4) In the details view use the `$routeParam` service to get the title of the movie clicked on and invoke the new `getDetails` method on the `Movie service` to return the details of that movie.

**Working Plunk**

http://plnkr.co/edit/zSyatT8JAHoBUQ3D2Zs6?p=preview

Comment: Thank u your method really works, but what if i want to add the title of the film or other attributes instead of all the information in the detail view ? there is any way of accessing that properties or this simple adds all which is in the json file ? in my case i need to access that properties because i have an array of actors in the json file and in the view is supposed to be a button that shows that  particular array in the selected movie.

Comment: Sure it could be.  It's only a matter of how your data is structured.  You could have a link inside details that says actors and it passes the movie parameter to the actors view and the actors controller has the logic for displaying the actors.

Comment: could you add it to the previous example ? because i cant figured out how to display them . in others codes I have seen something like : {{movie.Title}} for accessing the title for example but your code is totally different .